# Change a output value of a field in a view

Tags: views

I've a view where one of the fields 'titleColor' has the option to return '#000000', '#FFFFFF' or '#FF0000'. I need to show instead of this values 'black', 'white', and 'red'. How can I do it? I've use in other cases [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional)  module, but I only can insert one else clause.

I hope you can help me,

Thank you very much.

Comment: how about creating a tax vocab for the options and values, then link these to the 'titleColor' field?

Comment: if memory serves, you can create multiple fields that are conditional on the first - it would display if the value matched, or show nothing if it didn't. So creating a field conditional on the value being #000000, and then creating another conditional on #ffffff and so on...

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use the views feature "rewrite result", combined with [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

**Note**: this module only has an alfa version as of today, but it's used in over 71K sites anyway.